# If Statement bash command

Tags: bash, if-statement, integer, compare

I am having a problem with this code:

```
highmem="58.0"
counter=1
while [ $counter = 1 ];
do
    #sleep 5
    mem=`ps -C ats -o pid=,%mem= | awk {'print $2'}`
    echo $mem
    echo $highmem
    if [ "$mem" -gt "$highmem" ]
    then
        echo test
    fi
done
```

Getting `./memtest: line 9: [: 20.3: integer expression expected`.

I can't figure it out what I'm doing wrong. I assume I'm comparing integer to text?

Comment: $highmem contains no integer. $mem contains no integer. Add a `done` as last line.

Comment: Please take a look: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: thre is a done at the end . The value of the mem & memhigh are as follow  20.3 & 58.0 ..  this is just a test run ..

Comment: No bypass this issue using bash substitution (see last line of my answer). If a variable `var` is structured `[0-9]+\.[0-9]`, you can multiply it by ten by removing the period: `${var//./}`. Then it becomes an integer and it can be compared to another integer.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple things wrong with this code:

1. As *Cyrus* noted, you are missing a `done` at the end of the script, to end the loop.
2. `[ $counter = 1 ]` is not a valid comparison, you should use `[ $counter -eq 1 ]`
3. This loop will never end since the value of `counter` is never changed.
4. Apparently the values of `mem` and `highmem` are not both integers. Which you should notice from the print statements. Since both variables seem to be floats with a single digit after the period, simply multiply them by 10 and then compare them. This can be achieved as follows: `if [ "${mem//./}" -gt "${highmem//./}" ]`.

Comment: no i fixed it by adding == or >  u cannot use eq for this comparison

Comment: The `eq` is for the first one and can most definitely be used to compare ints. The second one can be done using `gt` by removing the period as I noted.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was two fold - first I was using -GT  rather than > sign. The other problem was that I was comparing 11.6 to 60 .. So I was comparing text to numeric.
The simple work around was to round up or just remove  the point or fraction out of the equation and then just do the work. There are may ways of doing thsi I just did it with awk and cut.  So at the end my highmem was equal a whole number with no fraction as well as the mem so both number were turned to whole to compare

Thanks for all your helps